# Bottle python web framework ,style sheet is not referenced in template

Tags: python, bottle

1. I have two question from bottle python web framework

   Question 1. In my website http://localhost:8080/home

   i am browsing via browse button to fetch excel file.i will process
   excel file i want to show the data in same
   http://localhost:8080/home  page.

   But when i google, they asked me to create template.

   Do we have only option to go for template  or any possibility to
   display in the same home page

   Question 2:

   I created template file and able to show results in the template but
   i style sheet  is not reflected in the template.

   i tried  href =/static/style.css i tried  href
   =/app/static/style.css i tried  like URL  get_url('static',

   Thanks Mani.

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you are rendering anything, you definately need a template. Of course, you can create this template in a flexible way, but it's up to you.
When it comees to the second question, the url should be put in quotation marks. [Compare](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp)

Comment: Thanks gonczor. I understand that in bottle web framework,we cant display output in html files rather we need to display in the template file.